# I want to delete files from multiple directories expect an image

Tags: php

I want to delete files from multiple direcories in PHP. The problem is when the code is run it deletes everything. I have a main folder which has a lots of folders in it. Those folders have files that i want to delete except that file in $filesToKeep variable. I'm a beginner PHP developer, and i really don't know how could i find the problame. If there is an another easier way to delete those files could be helpful too.

Here is my code:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
      $objects = scandir($dir);
      foreach ($objects as $object) {
        if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
          if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
        }
      }
      reset($objects);
      rmdir($dir);
    }
  }
 $filesToKeep = array(
     'partner-profil-480.jpg'
 );
 $dirList = glob('*');
 foreach ($dirList as $file) {
   if (!in_array($file, $filesToKeep)) {
       if (is_dir($file)) {
           rrmdir($file);
       } else {
           unlink($file);
       }//END IF
   }//END IF
}//END FOREACH LOOP
?>
```

Comment: Print out `$file` inside your `foreach` to see what it looks like and if it could possibly match a file you want to keep

Comment: I tried to print it but it didn't give me back anything. I can only see the file structure which is an another code before the delete function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution a while ago just i forgot to post it.
Here it is:

```
$path = "yourpath";

function dirToArray($dir) { 

$filesToKeep = array(
     'your-file-to-keep'
 );
    $contents = array();
    foreach (scandir($dir) as $node) {      
  
        if ($node == '.' || $node == '..') continue;

        if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $node)) {  
           
            $contents[$node] = dirToArray($dir . '/' . $node); 
 
        } else {
            $contents[] = $node;
            print_r(json_encode($node, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
            if(!in_array($node, $filesToKeep)){

                unlink($dir . '/' . $node);

            }
        }
        rmdir($dir . '/' . $node);
        
    }
    
}
$r = dirToArray($path);
print_r($r);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).